Flutter Windows Japanese Textfield does not work properly when setState is present in onChanged(v) or inputFormatters are added
Steps to reproduce
flutter issue

Focus the text field and type, or unfocus the text field and type
Shows unwanted suggestion, In case of no focus (touching out), the hint is still displayed while typing. Then when you focus the text field and type again, the characters will be filled in a lot
Actual results

Expected results


Code sample
TextFormField(
                enableSuggestions: false,
                enableIMEPersonalizedLearning: false,
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: _textController,
              )

Flutter Doctor output

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3593], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.19.0 on channel stable at C:\Users\ducph\fvm\versions\3.19.0
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision bae5e49bc2 (4 months ago), 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
• Engine revision 04817c99c9
• Dart version 3.3.0
• DevTools version 2.31.1


[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\ducph\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run flutter doctor --android-licenses to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.


[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe


[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.6)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.7.34221.43
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0


[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)


[√] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\ducph\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter


[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3593]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 124.0.6367.208
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 125.0.2535.79


[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

